# Python using PRE-FETCH on Oracle 10

Tags: python, oracle10g

```
import cx_Oracle
import wx

print "Start..." + str(wx.Now())

base = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxx', port, 'yyyy')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user name, password, base)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('select data from t_table')

li_row = cursor.fetchall()

data = []

for row in li_row:

    data.append(row[0])

cursor.close()

connection.close()

print "End..." + str(wx.Now())

print "DONE!!!"
```

Is there a way to integrate pre-fetch in this program? My goal is to get data from database as quick as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching 10000 rows...

cursor.arraysize = 10000